# Generate schedule planner between two given dates

Tags: datetime, calendar, date, datenumber

I am trying to generate a table with the following format:

[image]

I am looking for a way to generate the dates given the initial week (In this case Jun 3 - 7)

I tried using the package `datenumber` but I am only able to set a counter for the initial date (Jun 3, 2019) using `\datedate` but I obtained the long date format "June 3, 2019".

```
\usepackage{datenumber}
\newcommand{\dnext}{
\addtocounter{datenumber}{7}\setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}
\datedate
}
\begin{document}
\setdatenumber{2019}{6}{3}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    Week  & Dates & Activity\\
    1 & \datedate & Some values \\
    2 &\pnext & Some values \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

My questions are basically the following two:

- Deal with the two counters
- Change the format to the desired one.

I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your MWE is really representative if what you are trying to do then I would write a macro that just accepts a comma separated list of "activities" and produces the table from this data. In any case, this would allow you to produce

[image]

using

```
\activities{Walked dog, Ate lunch, Slept}
```

The trick is to use `\docsvlist` from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package, together with some gratuitous styling via the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package.

With regards to formatting the dates, [datenumber](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datenumber) defines counters `dateday` and `datemonth` for the day and month. So my first thought was that it was enough to wrap these into a macro where you add 4 to the current day:

```
\newcommand\weekdate{%
  \ifcase\value{datemonth}%
    \or Jan \or Feb \or Mar \or Apr \or May \or Jun
    \or Jul \or Aug \or Sep \or Oct \or Nov \or Dec
    \fi
    \arabic{dateday}--\the\numexpr\arabic{dateday}+4\relax%
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not really work because, for example, January does not have 35 days. To take the lengths of the months properly into account you need something like:

```
\newcommand\weekdate{%
  \setmydatebynumber{\the\numexpr\thedatenumber+4}{endofweekyear}{endofweekmonth}{endofweekday}
  \ifcase\value{datemonth}%
    \or Jan \or Feb \or Mar \or Apr \or May \or Jun
    \or Jul \or Aug \or Sep \or Oct \or Nov \or Dec
    \fi
    \arabic{dateday}--\arabic{endofweekday}%
}
```

This works but it is very slow to compile. I'm also not sure about writing `Jul 29-2` instead of `Jul 29-Aug 2`, but this seems to be what the OP asks for. It is easy enough to modify the code above to produce `Jul 29-Aug 2` if this is what is really wanted.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcounter{endofweekday}
\newcounter{endofweekmonth}
\newcounter{endofweekyear}
\newcommand\weekdate{%
  \setmydatebynumber{\the\numexpr\thedatenumber+4}{endofweekyear}{endofweekmonth}{endofweekday}
  \ifcase\value{datemonth}%
    \or Jan \or Feb \or Mar \or Apr \or May \or Jun
    \or Jul \or Aug \or Sep \or Oct \or Nov \or Dec
    \fi
    \arabic{dateday}--\arabic{endofweekday}%
}
\newcounter{activity}
\newcommand\activities[1]{
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{%
  \stepcounter{activity}%
  \setdatebynumber{\thedatenumber}%
  \arabic{activity}
    & \weekdate \addtocounter{datenumber}{7}%
    & ##1 \\
  }
  \begin{tabular}{cll}\toprule
    Week  & Dates & Activity\\\midrule
    \docsvlist{#1}
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
  \setdatenumber{2019}{7}{22}
  \activities{Walked dog, Ate lunch, Slept}
\end{document}
```

You could further embellish this by making the starting date an optional argument to `\activities`.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew that helps a lot!!